# Android app naming guidelines, first word as company

Tags: android

I recently received an email from Google Play regarding my apps name. The app is a reader for the webcomic xkcd and it's title is "xkcd Viewer".  I learned that new naming conventions state you cannot use a company name (xkcd) as the first word in the app title.

My question is, does this apply to the Play Store listing name only? Or does it also apply to the app title (the one you see when you open the app from your device)?

The email I received:

> This is a notification that your application submission, xkcd Reader, for package ID ---------, has been rejected. If this submission was an update to an existing app, the version published prior to this update is still available on Google Play.
>
> Please address the issue described below, then submit an update with your changes.
>
> REASON FOR REJECTION: Violation of the spam provision of the Content Policy. Please refer to the keyword spam policy help article for more information.
>
> Do not use others' branding or product names at the start of your app title without permission. This implies association and is misleading for users. Instead, use "for [ product or brandinsert name ]."
>
> Incorrect: "Android MediaPlayer"
>
> Correct: "MediaPlayer for Android"
>
> All submission rejections are tracked. Repeated rejections due to policy violations will result in app suspension, at which point this app will count as a strike against the good standing of your developer account and no longer be available on Google Play.
>
> This notification also serves as notice for other apps in your catalog. You can avoid future submission rejections and/or app suspensions by immediately ensuring that no other apps in your catalog are in violation of (but not limited to) the above policy. Before publishing applications, please ensure your apps’ compliance with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Content Policy.
>
> If you feel we have made this determination in error, you can visit this Google Play Help Center article.
>
> The Google Play Team

Comment: This seems like the thing that you should be asking Google Play about.

Comment: i think you must use uppercase for first letter. so it should be Xkcd Reader

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Maybe, the problem here was the issue using a product name as the first word. Thank you though!

Comment: I just got one of these, and believe me it is a huge improvement over an earlier suspension I received which was not explained to me in a manner that I could act upon with any confidence at all.  I ended up just leaving that app suspended for fear that my resubmittal would be rejected with dire consequences to my account.  This suspension email, by contrast, gives clear instructions regarding what is to be corrected, and thus is easy to act upon.  Kudos to Google for improving its process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, does this apply to the Play Store listing name only? Or does it also apply to the app title (the one you see when you open the app from your device)?

The policy applies to both cases.

You may change the name of your app to "Viewer for xkcd" or "Reader for xkcd" similar to that's shown in the example.

Hope this helps.